# How to Avoid Azure App Service Plans to Scale Down Automatically

Tags: azure, scale, azure-web-app-service

I would like to ask you if there is a way to avoid App Service Plans from Azure to scale down automatically. For instance, I configured an App Service Plan with the following pricing tier: Basic: 1 Medium; nevertheless, if my app is idle for some time the pricing tier of that App Service Plan changes to Shared. I do not know if that is a standard behavior, financially it makes sense; however, from a technical point of view, I do need at least a Basic Service Plan at all times since I am using some GDI+ features not available in a shared environment (where in fact my app starts crashing).

While in developing, creating and deploying directly web apps from within Visual Studio, and later scaling the app to a Basic Service Plan never changed back to Free set by default... But now in production using a Pay-As-You-Go subscription I am having this problem, that now is becoming very annoying.

I hope that anyone may help me figure out how to avoid the behavior stated earlier, in order to force my App Service Plan to remain in at least a Basic pricing tier, even while my app is idle; or in this case, at least force my App Service Plan to scale up from Shared to Basic once the app is not idle anymore.

Comment: I'd suggest you open a support ticket. I have heard of a similar case with app service plan auto scale down where support was able to identify the issue and offer a fix

Answer (score 1):

Changes to the App Plan are not automatic.  Someone is doing them.  Look into your Azure Operation logs and I bet you'll find the culprit.  Or maybe you have a limit on the spend in your Azure account and it converts everything to free plan once that cap runs out?

Comment: Igorek, I looked into the Operation Logs / Audit logs as suggested and I did find, for instance, the last couple of operations (two entries “Update hosting plan”) I did several hours while trying to Scale Up manually from Shared to Basic (B2), but I could not find any evidence of someone or something updating back the app service plan from Basic (B2) to Shared from that time to this morning. Any other thoughts? By the way, I created an alert on each App Service Plan registered in the event of ‘Scale Down’ expecting to gather more information on this issue.

Comment: Igorek, as for your second comment, I shall say that the account is only a few days old, so even though it is now a Pay-As-You-Go subscription, since I deliberately remove the Spending Limit, supposedly the subscription may still be running on the $200 USD credits from the Free Trial; may this condition be responsible for the current switching (scaling down) behavior of the app service plans?

Comment: Sounds like time to call support then

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I configured an App Service Plan with the following pricing tier: Standard: 1 Small; but, for some reason, the pricing tier of that App Service Plan changes to Shared. I was using a Pay-As-You-Go subscription without spent limit!!

To solve the problem, I had to create a **new subscription** (Pay-As-You-Go), change the App Plan Service for the new subscription and, finally, scale up to new pricing tier.