# App Service Plan Keeps Scaling Down Or Getting Corrupted

Tags: azure, scale, traffic, azure-traffic-manager

I have a Trial subscription and a very simple setup.

- Traffic Manager (e.g. tm1)

  - Endpoint 1 (e.g. ep1) - Weight of 1

    - Web App (e.g. wa1)

      - App Service Plan (e.g. asp1) - S1 Standard @ East US 2
  - Endpoint 2 (e.g. ep2) - Weight of 1

    - Web App 2 (e.g. wa2)

      - App Service Plan 2 (e.g. asp2) - S1 Standard @ Central US

All I am trying to do is play around with Traffic Manager redirection by setting the weights (e.g. from 1 to 1000), stopping/starting the web apps, etc.

I *never* change anything about the service plans.  All I do is stop or start the web apps or set the weights of the endpoints to route traffic.

I have found time and time again that one or both of the following happens:

- ASP2 gets scaled down to Shared (from S1 Standard) - This causes issues as Shared doesn't support Traffic Manager.
- ASP1 gets "lost".  When I go to the portal to see if it too was scaled down, the portal just spins.

This is really, really annoying for such a simple setup.

Thoughts?

Comment: This may be a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084088/how-to-avoid-azure-app-service-plans-to-scale-down-automatically